# crawling size dropdown in NordStromRack Website

Tags: php, dom

I am **scraping** nordstromrack website using 'simple html dom' library. I am done with **scraping** other attributes, just the size. I am not sure if the size is coming through ajax or api etc. I can't see any ajax call, but I know without clicking on size dropdown, its not loaded and doesn't appear in source code.
Can anyone help me find how they are rendering size. Example URL is
https://www.nordstromrack.com/s/nike-air-max-motion-2-athletic-sneaker/6039547

Any help will be appreciated in advance.

Comment: Could you add the code you currently have?

Comment: From what I can tell, they append an absolute positioned div, right where the button for the "dropdown" is, so they keep the width of the button and add it there. The data of the sizes is inside their `window.__INITIAL_CONFIG__` there is a `size` property in there

Comment: @Ant, Yeah I noticed that and scrapped the json code inside initial config. But I thought it is for their android app.

Comment: Apparently not. It has a bunch of data in there, from Android app and logo data, to the layout of the menubar... So most of the JS on the page references that data. As far as scrapping webpages go, I think you hit the jackpot. I do not know how they could make it easier for you. You get both the layout and parseable data!